# No module named 'cv2' during importing in python

Tags: python

I followed the instructions to install opencv in ubuntu from the link https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-18-04/#disqus_thread.

The module is installed properly. But when I import it in python I get the error "No module named 'cv2'"
What can I do?

Comment: Which python you are using?>

Comment: is `cv2` part of the "installed packages list"? You may print the list by running an interactive python session and `import pip`, then `for p in ["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in pip.get_installed_distributions()]: print(p)`

Comment: @VaibhavJadhav  python 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python3:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 1):

To install the latest stable version of `opencv-python 4.1.2.30` with `pip`, use the below command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```