# Import "cv2" could not be resolved

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, opencv

I've installed python and opencv by using the correct commands in the cmd, but when I type in 'import cv2' in a python then I get the error in visual studio code and I can't find any solution online how to fix this

```
Import "cv2" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)
```

More of the error in the terminal

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Comment: Can you detail the problem more, such as showing the full error log?

Comment: Try saving and running the code. Pylance has a problem where it wont recognize an error is resolved until the file is saved or executed.

Comment: @TechnologyDev Hi! I've added more of the error, but that's all it's showing

Comment: @IsmailHafeez I've saved it and tried to run it but still have the same issue

Comment: How did you install cv2? Using pip?

Comment: @IsmailHafeez I used 'pip install opencv-python'

Comment: What? You didn't install cv2?

Comment: `import package` does not install it. It just imports it if it already exists.

Comment: @IsmailHafeez Sorry I didn't read what you said properly and yes I used pip to install it

Comment: Let’s compare it to pyglet and OpenGL. To use pyglet, you _first_ need to do `sudo apt-get install opengl` (on Debian/Ubuntu) then do `pip3 install pyglet`.

Comment: Wait, that reminds me, I think you have to do `pip3 install cv2`. Sometimes I think that `pip install cv2` only installs for python2, not python3.

Comment: @TechnologyDev I got the error ```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2``` when I entered that in cmd

Comment: If you're using VS Code, just restart the ide...
Ran into the same problem, after restarting, works fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named 'cv2' during importing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561302/no-module-named-cv2-during-importing-in-python)

Comment: @TechnologyDev getting error 'unable to locate opengl pyglet, yes I did apt-get update first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that Visual Studio does not support the latest Python 3.8, so I had to use PyCharm as an IDE.

Answer (score 18):

It just happened to me and I solved it installing both opencv-python and opencv-python-headless with pip and reloading the Visual Studio Code window right after it.

To install the needed packages, just run this command in the terminal:

```
$ pip install opencv-python opencv-python-headless
```

Comment: Worked for me (JupyterLab on Saturn Cloud)

Comment: didn't work for me in docker environment using python:3.9-slim as base image. There is an issue with libGL.so

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that its using the correct version of Python; e.g., I installed Python from the windows store, which is working:

[image: this version is working for me]

However, if I use another one, it does not work:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue so I installed opencv-python-headless (install opencv-python if not earlier) and reloaded the VScode window.

```
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

However, some methods like imshow() kept failing:

```
cv2.error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

This was resolved by installing opencv-contrib-python. You can install it by running the following code in your terminal:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal (`cmd` if Windows) run the following (make sure that you're on the current working environment):

```
pip install opencv-python
```

then:

```
pip install opencv-python-headless
```

Comment: Yeah still doesn't work and just says unresolved import

Answer (score 1):

I just uninstalled the older python version and installed a new one again. That is probably the simplest and the most hassle-free one in my mind. Stick to version 3.8.8, that should do the trick. Also no worries about maintaining multiple versions of python in the system. It is indeed true that the lack of support from VS is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am on a mac and struggle with this and this is the best way to do it, when ur in your .py file, on the lower left part of your vscode windown u will see the version of python you are using, click that and try different versions until your open cv command works, in my case, 3.8.8 worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with -

```
pip install opencv-python
```

If this command didn't solve the problem , it's may have the another way to solve this error.

If we run the command from virtualenv project terminal, it can't resolve `import cv2`

However, `opencv-python` is installed in your project directory. You can check the result:

```
pip show opencv-python
```

It may shows something like that.

```
(Screen_Rec-leAIY5iD) C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Screen_Rec>pip show opencv- 
python
Name: opencv-python
Version: 4.7.0.72
Summary: Wrapper package for OpenCV python bindings.
Home-page: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python
Author:
Author-email:
License: Apache 2.0
Location: C:\Users\Administrator\.virtualenvs\Screen_Rec 
leAIY5iD\Lib\site- 
packages
Requires: numpy, numpy, numpy, numpy, numpy
Required-by:
```

It's should be resolved by opening commad promt and run as administrator:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Hope. Its resolve the import errors of following:

```
Import "cv2" could not be resolved Pylance (reportMissingImports)
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue in VS Code and the problem was solved simply by selecting the Python interpreter again. Didn't have to install anything.

1. CTRL + SHIFT + P
2. Type and Choose "Python: Select Interpreter"
3. Select desired version of Python

[image]